# Do I need to use ProxyPassReverse if I'm using mod rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I am using mod rewrite to mask the context root of my application. For example,

```
RewriteRule ^/directory/(.*) balancer://appcluster/directory/$1 [P]
```

The appcluster looks like this:

```
<Proxy balancer://appcluster>
BalancerMember http://localhost:8080/App route=app_01 keepalive=On loadfactor=1 ttl=300 min=3 smax=5 max=15

ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid timeout=120 nofailover=On
</Proxy>
```

Do I need to use `ProxyPassReverse` at all? I used to use it because my old webserver code looked like this:

```
ProxyPass /App balancer://appcluster lbmethod=byrequests stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid timeout=120 nofailover=On

ProxyPassReverse /App http://localhost:9013/App
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `ProxyPassReverse` is used to change the headers sent by the app (appcluster) to Apache, before Apache sends it the browser. For example, if the app sits at http://localhost:9013/, and it tries to redirect the browser to, say, `/new_location/`, then it will respond with a redirect and location header of http://localhost:9013/new_location/, and Apache will take this and send it off to the browser. Problem is, the browser (assuming it's somewhere else) then tries to send a request to http://localhost:9013/new_location/, and gets an error.

What ProxyPassReverse does is intercepts those headers, and rewrites them so that they match what the Apache server that's doing the proxying looks like. So if my apache server is hosting http://myhost.com/ and I have a `ProxyPass` that points `/` to http://localhost:9013/App, if the application sitting at localhost:9013 returns a redirect to http://localhost:9013/App/new_location/, I'll need to use `ProxyPassReverse` so that it gets rewritten to http://myhost.com/new_location/ by Apache before sending the request back to the browser.

If you aren't issuing redirects, it's not going to be an issue, but it doesn't hurt to have it there in case a 301/302 redirect is returned. As far as mod_rewrite, the RewriteRule applies to the request going to the App, and not the response coming from the App. So they are mutually exclusive events.

Comment: So would my proxy pass reverse be the following: ProxyPassReverse /App/directory http://localhost:9013/App/directory ?

Comment: I think what you have is correct. Though I've seen people use it in such a way where the url on the right is the outside domain and not localhost. My Jboss deployments use ProxyPassReverse just like you have it and they redirect just fine.

Comment: Very nice Explanation about ProxyPassReverse and the need for it. @jon lin .. Thank you

Comment: I want to preserve the url in the browser with the following
all example.xyz/us/en/search should be proxied to example.us/us/en/search.
I have the following rules.
        ProxyPassMatch  "^/(.{2,3})/(.{2,3})/(.*)/?$"  "http://example.$1/$1/$2/$3"
        ProxyPassReverse "^/(.*)$" "http://example.xyz/$1"
except for 404 the url is being changed to example.us/us/en/search.