# Proxypass and proxypassreverse set up to access intranet images, css, and Javascript files over internet

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

We have set up a Wordpress blog in our intranet and I am trying to access the blog on our internet site.
The blog site is running at myintranet.host:80/blog, where as the public site is mypublicsite.com. 
We are able to access the blog at mypublicsite.com/blog with below Apache httpd.conf entry( in mypublicsite.com server) inside the network but getting 'net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED' error when trying to access any static content, such as images/.js/css files but loads the blog text fine outside our VPN/network.

`<Location /blog/>
     ProxyPass myintranet.host:80/blog
     ProxyPassReverse myintranet.host:80/blog
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
    </Location>`

Also added below entry in WP site's httpd.conf to fix CORS error when accessing the blog content from mypublicsite.com/blog URL.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|jpeg|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "mypublicsite.com"
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Isn't the purpose of ProxyPass ProxyPassReverse help with this scenario, to avoid the need to expose the blog site on the internet?

Am I missing anything here since I saw similar question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455199/proxypass-failing) but it's not working for us?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue with ProxyPass, some of the settings in the WordPress site had intranet server URL, which caused the css, JavaScript, and other files not to load outside our network/internet. The issue got resolved when I made the changes to WP settings to use external site URL.